# passing textfield value to of string iphone

Tags: iphone

In my application i have following fields:

```
testMsg.fromEmail = @"support@gadsfd.co.uk";
testMsg.toEmail = @"%@",email;
testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gdsadfds.co.uk";
testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
testMsg.login = @"support@dgadfda.co.uk";
testMsg.pass = @"ngdfadfdadfa";
testMsg.subject = @"The Money Shop Order Confirmation";
testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; // smtp.gmail.com doesn't work without TLS!
```

In testMsg.toEmail=@"some email"; i want to pass string from textField.text=email;

How can i do that

Comment: Why its unclear? it clearly says i want to pass testMsg.toEmail=@""; in "" value from textField.test. what was unclear in that.Please let me know

Comment: it is unclear because you asked to assign an assignment to an assignment. - very confusing

Comment: Why doesn't testMsg.toEmail = textField.text work? Have you tried that?

Comment: also because you gave very little background info

Comment: @Alex ok i agree .so now can u solve it please

Comment: explain more about your class, try logging some stuff?

Comment: No its nothing to do with class. i have just simple question. i want to pass testfield.text value in between" " i.e.  @"";  Thats it. or in other words i want to pass textField.text value in place of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)email{
    NSString *emailRegex = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"; 
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];

}

if([self validateEmailWithString:textField.text){
    textMsg.toEmail = textField.text;
}else{
      NSLog(@"Email was not valid");
}
```

**According to your comment**

```
- (NSMutableArray*)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)emails {

    NSString *emailRegx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

    NSMutableArray *validEmails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *emailList = [emails componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    for (NSString *_email in emailList){

         NSPredicate *emailChecker = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex]; 
         if ([emailChecker evaluateWithObject:_email])
              [validEmails addObject:_email];
    }
    return [validEmails autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I hope you type valid email address to your textfield, if not then there is solution for that as well. :)

Comment: i got my answer. thanks mate for help. I was wondring one more thing. if i have to pass two emails. then how can i pass in .

Comment: Edited my answer according to your question :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but  i have put all conditions emailRegx etc. earlier. i just want to send email to two different ids. my code is in question

Comment: No matter :) It was just the safeguard.

Comment: So how can i send email to more then one receipeant. im using smtpsend library which is third party library

Comment: you just need to use ; for multiple recipients. for ex: **test1@test1.com ; test2@test2.com** thats it. but the in my above code you should use **componentsSeparatedByString:@";"** not with the single ,(comma).

Comment: Surely you should declare `emailRegx` outside the loop body... should you not?

Answer (score 1):

An NSString object in objective-C must be assigned a reference to a string. This is why your hard-coded strings in the source have to be preceded by an @ sign. If you wish to reference an already existing string, for instance `textField.text`. You can do so with a simple assignment expression.

```
textField.text = @"test@test.com";
testMsg.toEmail = textField.text;
```

Comment: i Got textField.text=MSG.  i have stored email id in MSG earlier.